Add custom search bar in SharePoint Page
I have a SharePoint page that has a document library as a web part. Currently the search bar at the top of the screen searches the entire site however, I want to add a web part that just searches the document library web part.
I understand there is a search box web part but it is not displayed for me.
Is this possible?

i think the best solution is using the pnp search webpart if you can add it https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/

You can add search box to SharePoint Online modern page using PnP Modern Search web parts.
Here, are the high-level steps for the same:

Deploy the PnP Modern Search package:

Download the PnP Modern Search package from the PnP GitHub repository.
Go to your SharePoint Admin Center, navigate to “More features,” and select “Apps.”
Create or open your App Catalog and upload the PnP Modern Search package file.
Deploy the package to your tenant.


Add the PnP Search Web Parts to your page:

Edit the SharePoint page where you want to add the search box.
In the web parts list, search for “PnP” and select “PnP Search Box” to add it to your page.
Next, add the “PnP Search Results” web part to the same page.


Connect the Search Box to the Search Results:

Edit the properties of the “PnP Search Results” web part.
Connect it to the “PnP Search Box” web part by configuring the web part properties.


Optional: Add Search Filters:

If you want to refine search results, add the “PnP Search Filters” web part.
Connect the “PnP Search Filters” web part to the “PnP Search Results” web part to enable filtering based on search results.


Configure and Save:

Customize the search results layout, refiners, and other settings as needed.
Save and publish your page.




@Nichi - Please accept and upvote this answer if it is helpful to you. Thanks.
